# How to convert GUI to path on Windows with Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file, qt

Clicking on "my computer" in the start menu returns a GUID link instead of a direct link. For example:

`::{20B04FE1-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08012B30309D}`

How can I convert it to a normal path so that I can get a list of directories and files with the help of `QDir`?

**UPDATE**

I'm not trying to get a list of drives. It is easily done with Qt. I just want to know that a user clicked My Computer in the start menu. (My application can replace Windows Explorer).

Comment: Normally one would call [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`CSIDL_DRIVES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the second argument for this sort of thing, but I don't think `CSIDL_DRIVES` has a physical path representation. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking there at an item in the Shell Namespace, not in the filesystem.

Introduction to the Shell Namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx

The shell shows many things which don't exist as files, My Computer being one. The Desktop is another - the shell desktop is a merged view of the All Users desktop folder, your personal desktop folder, and a few other items which are purely virtual like the recycle bin.

To find out more about the item you can use `SHParseDisplayName` to convert a name to an `ITEMIDLIST`.

If you intend to offer a replacement for Explorer, good luck!